# ssh works in school network but doesn't work from outside

Tags: ssh, internet, routing

When I'm connected to my school network, I am able to ssh into my desktop computer at home just fine from my laptop. But when I'm home, trying to ssh into the same desktop from the same laptop always gives me time out error:

```
ssh: connect to host <my IP address> port 22: Connection timed out
```

I enabled port forwarding on port 22 in my router, installed openssh and everything is set up so that I'm able to ssh when I'm at school.

On my home desktop, the command

```
sudo netstat grep | grep sshd
```

returns

```
tcp   0   0   0.0.0:22     0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN   sshd
```

I do not understand why this won't work outside my school network. Currently when I ssh into my home desktop computer from my laptop connected to my school network, I'm using the IP address of my desktop.

MORE INFO:

when I run

```
ssh -vv <myusername>@<my-ip-address>
```

I get

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.01f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying for options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <IP address> [<IP address>] port 22.
debug1: connect to address <IP address> port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: School may be using NAT. Your school desktop IP may not be accessible from outside the school's LAN. Alternately school may be blocking, using a firewall, external ssh connections. You may have to troubleshoot this one with your school's IT guys.

Comment: hmm okay. I'll contact the IT guys and see if they can solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your responses to numerous questions, the actual configuration is:

Desktop is at your school.  You can ssh into it from your laptop when your laptop is connected to the school network.

You cannot connect your laptop to the school workstation desktop when your laptop is outside the school network.

It is highly unlikely that the workstation in your lab has a static registered Internet reachable IP address.  Or even one issued by DHCP.  In addition, connections could be going through a NAT translation before packets go onto the Internet which means that the machines IP address inside the school will be different from the IP address that's visible outside the school.  Plus, various incoming port requests such as 22 could be blocked by a firewall.

Any issues there would need to be resolved by the school IT staff.  They can create a static NAT entry in their border router so that you will know what IP to ssh into from the Internet.  They may or may not be willing to do this.

In the meantime, as a handy tool to troubleshoot problems like this, install nmap on your laptop.

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Then, from home or somewhere outside of school,

```
ping The.IP.you.think.connects.to.your.machine.from.the.Internet

nmap The.IP.you.think.connects.to.your.machine.from.the.Internet
```

If ping returns nothing or if nmap doesn't show that port 22 is open you'll never be able to ssh into it.  For the reasons mentioned above, it's possible that nmap isn't actually probing YOUR machine so if ssh fails to authenticate, that could well be the reason.

Needless to say, you need to know the IP address that's visible from the Internet that will connect to your desktop workstation at school.  And nothing such as a firewall can be blocking the ssh connection dialog. If that is the root of your issue, open that up as a new question since it doesn't have anything (directly) to do with why ssh doesn't work.

To find out your Internet IP address, on the desktop workstation at school go to this URL:

```
http://whatismyipaddress.com/
```

Comment: It should be made known that it is entirely possible the school does not permit this and therefore is why they NAT things.  Most smaller schools (not universities) fall into the category of places that don't permit this kind of thing anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt to ssh into the school network might be blocked because the IP address cannot be reached from outside.

Ask your school IT folks if you can: first ssh into your school firewall/DHCP (with a static IP), then from their ssh into whatever IP address you want. They will provide correct public IP and private credentials if the school policy allows.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address of the machine you are trying to ssh into from your home LAN is different than the Internet facing IP address of your router.

If you do a traceroute to your home desktop / ssh server from school, you'll see that the packet goes to your router and is then forwarded to the ssh host which is on your local LAN and on the other side of the router.

From your home network you are directly connected to the same LAN as the Desktop / ssh server.  That is, your laptop IP and your desktop machine / ssh server IP will be on the same subnet.

If you ssh into the 192.168.0.x (or whatever) local address of the desktop / ssh server from home, that should work.

To find out your desktop / ssh server's local address:

```
ifconfig -a
```

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't 192.168.0.x local address which can only be accessed when you're in the same network? I am using DDNS that I registered in my router to access my desktop.

Comment: Your question indicates that you are having problems connecting from a laptop connected to your home LAN to a desktop running as an ssh server that is also on your home LAN.  Try as I suggested and that should work.  If this is not the case you need to re-word your question.  Or open a new question.

Comment: oh no the server is in school network and my home LAN is separate.

Comment: Please add the results of your desktop / ssh server ifconfig -a  I'm assuming it does not have a registered IP address.

Comment: no, i do have registered ip. I am using DDNS

Comment: Let's remove DDNS from the equation. That could be the source of your problem.  ssh into the IP address of your desktop from your laptop while both the desktop and your laptop are connected to your home network.

Comment: When both are connected to my school network, they work fine. I tried both DDNS and IP address. It's when I'm outside or somewhere else other than home

Comment: So you're hauling around your *DESKTOP* to school and to various other locations?

Comment: no. My desktop is at school. It's my workstation in my lab. I want to access my desktop that is sitting at my desk in school from home.

Comment: That's not the configuration you described in your original question.  So you need to follow the steps in my answer in reverse.  Forget using DDNS until this all gets sorted out.  Ping the IP address of your desktop workstation at school from home.  If that works, sudo apt-get install nmap and then nmap the IP address of the same IP.  If port 22 is listed then we'll go one way.  If it isn't, something (probably the school firewall) is blocking you.

Comment: And BTW, port forwarding port 22 at your router is for INCOMING ssh packets.  For what you are doing, the forwarding "may" be looping the ssh requests right back to you :(  We can probably get this fixed in ten minutes if you want to chat on IRC

Comment: Hmm I really want to but i'm not at home at the moment :( . Can I get back to you when i'm home? I did port forwarding at port 22 for my router at school which is for incoming ssh packets. I tried pinging the school desktop IP address from home and it didn't work. One of the comments said it could be the problem with school firewall or sth. If that's the case how do i check if it's a firewall issue?

Comment: I'll try to ping my school desktop IP address again when I get home and let you know.

Comment: If your lab router connects DIRECTLY to the Internet then this could be a relatively easy fix.  But if your router goes through the school network and then hits the Internet, there could be some major technical issues that your IT guys will need to help you with.  In any case, this really isn't a ssh issue.  It's a network connectivity matter.

Comment: tried to ping school desktop IP address and it didn't work. It seems like it goes through the school network and then hits the internet.  I'll have to contact the IT guys. Thank you for answering all my questions, really appreciate it.